# Accordion Custom Toggle (react-bootstrap) and componentDidUpdate() compatibility issue

Tags: reactjs

I am now implementing the react-bootstrap Accordion with the Custom Toggle with the reference below.

https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/accordion/

But if you have the componentDidUpdate() in your code, Accordion does not work.

1. You click the Accordion's Custom Toggle.
2. The Accordion Collapse expands.
3. But the componentDidUpdate() or componentDidMount() is kicked and it updates the screen.
   They extract data from the server by using fetch.
   This seems to be an issue.
4. The just expanded Accordion Collapse is immediately folded.
5. So you cannot expand the Accordion.

Anyone can provide me with any solution?

The entire code is as below.

```
import React from 'react';
import {Accordion, Card, useAccordionToggle, ListGroup} from 'react-bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

class EMP extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {employees: []}
    }
    
    componentDidMount() {
        fetch('/SQLite/employees')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(employees => this.setState({ employees }));
    }
    
    componentDidUpdate() {
        fetch('/SQLite/employees')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(employees => this.setState({ employees }));
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <EmployeeList employees={this.state.employees} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class EmployeeList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    
    render() {
        const CustomToggle = ({ children, eventKey }) => {
            const decoratedOnClick = useAccordionToggle(
                    eventKey, 
                    (e) =>{
                        var item = e.target.parentNode.children[0];
                        if(item.innerText.includes('▶',0)){
                            item.innerText = item.innerText.replace('▶', '▼');
                        }
                        else{
                            item.innerText = item.innerText.replace('▼', '▶');
                        }
                    }
                );

            return (
                <ListGroup.Item
                    onClick={decoratedOnClick}
                    style={{cursor: 'pointer', paddingBottom: '0', paddingTop: '0' }}
                >
                    {children}
                </ListGroup.Item>
            );
        }
        
        return (
            <Accordion defaultActiveKey='0'>
                <Card>
                    <Card.Header>
                        <CustomToggle eventKey='0'>▶ Click me!</CustomToggle>
                    </Card.Header>
                    <Accordion.Collapse eventKey='0'>
                        <Card.Body>Hello! Im the body</Card.Body>
                    </Accordion.Collapse>
                </Card>
                <Card>
                    <Card.Header>
                        <CustomToggle eventKey='1'>▶ Click me!</CustomToggle>
                    </Card.Header>
                    <Accordion.Collapse eventKey='1'>
                        <Card.Body>Hello! Im the body</Card.Body>
                    </Accordion.Collapse>
                </Card>
            </Accordion>
        )
    }
}

export default EMP;
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example of your component and where you have an issue.

Comment: Hi Drew. I provided the minimal reproducible code in the above section.

Comment: Other than I think `CustomToggle` ***shouldn't*** be defined in the render function your code works for me in this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/accordion-custom-toggle-react-bootstrap-and-componentdidupdate-compatibility-5p2vy?file=/src/App.js).

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason of the issue.

With the content of componentDidMount() and componentDidUpdate() without arrow function ( () => fetch() ), the app falls into an infinite loop.

1. render() is called.
2. this.setState() is called.
3. render() is called again.

To prevent this inifinite loop, you must write the arrow function in the componentDidmount().

So the correct and complete code is as below.

```
import React from 'react';
import {Accordion, Card, useAccordionToggle, ListGroup} from 'react-bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

class EMP extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {employees: []}
    }
    
    componentDidMount() {
        () => fetch('/SQLite/employees')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(employees => this.setState({ employees }));
    }
    
    componentDidUpdate() {
        () => fetch('/SQLite/employees')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(employees => this.setState({ employees }));
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
            <EmployeeList employees={this.state.employees} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class EmployeeList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    
    render() {
        const CustomToggle = ({ children, eventKey }) => {
            const decoratedOnClick = useAccordionToggle(
                    eventKey, 
                    (e) =>{
                        var item = e.target.parentNode.children[0];
                        if(item.innerText.includes('▶',0)){
                            item.innerText = item.innerText.replace('▶', '▼');
                        }
                        else{
                            item.innerText = item.innerText.replace('▼', '▶');
                        }
                    }
                );

            return (
                <ListGroup.Item
                    onClick={decoratedOnClick}
                    style={{cursor: 'pointer', paddingBottom: '0', paddingTop: '0' }}
                >
                    {children}
                </ListGroup.Item>
            );
        }
        
        return (
            <Accordion defaultActiveKey='0'>
                <Card>
                    <Card.Header>
                        <CustomToggle eventKey='0'>▶ Click me!</CustomToggle>
                    </Card.Header>
                    <Accordion.Collapse eventKey='0'>
                        <Card.Body>Hello! Im the body</Card.Body>
                    </Accordion.Collapse>
                </Card>
                <Card>
                    <Card.Header>
                        <CustomToggle eventKey='1'>▶ Click me!</CustomToggle>
                    </Card.Header>
                    <Accordion.Collapse eventKey='1'>
                        <Card.Body>Hello! Im the body</Card.Body>
                    </Accordion.Collapse>
                </Card>
            </Accordion>
        )
    }
}

export default EMP;
```